# How can I get all photos in one post using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-fql

```
  {
    "id": "11882030_4952296803730", 
    "from": {
      "name": "xxx", 
      "id": "11882030"
    }, 
    "message": "test", 
    "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/408410_4952294483672_298434229_s.jpg", 
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=4952294483672&set=pcb.4952296803730&type=1&relevant_count=2", 
    "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yx/r/og8V99JVf8G.gif", 
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "Comment", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/11882030/posts/4952296803730"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Like", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/11882030/posts/4952296803730"
      }
    ], 
    "privacy": {
      "description": "Friends", 
      "value": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
      "friends": "", 
      "networks": "", 
      "allow": "", 
      "deny": ""
    }, 
    "place": {
      "id": "471607792876974", 
      "name": "TTT", 
      "location": {
        "street": "", 
        "zip": "", 
        "latitude": x, 
        "longitude": x
      }
    }, 
    "type": "photo", 
    "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
    "object_id": "4952294483672",
    "application": {
      "name": "Facebook for iPhone", 
      "namespace": "fbiphone", 
      "id": "6628568379"
    }, 
    "created_time": "2013-01-17T01:29:59+0000", 
    "updated_time": "2013-01-17T01:29:59+0000", 
    "comments": {
      "count": 0
    }
  }
```

As above, I posted a status with two photos. I can get the first photo's thumb URL in `picture` and the relevant link & count information in `link`.

But how can I get each photo's specific URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FQL often provides more information than Graph API. You have to use the `attachment` parameter of the `stream` **FQL** table to get all the attached photos.

```
SELECT attachment FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id = me() 
   AND post_id="11882030_4952296803730"
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "attachment": {
        "media": [
          {
            "href": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=471082296...", 
            "alt": "", 
            "type": "photo", 
            "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/5826...", 
            "photo": {
              "aid": "4391039135", 
              "pid": "439104482145", 
              "fbid": 471507, 
              "owner": 102832, 
              "index": 1, 
              "width": 485, 
              "height": 172, 
              "images": [
                {
                  "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hph...", 
                  "width": 130, 
                  "height": 46
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ], 
        "name": "", 
        "caption": "", 
        "description": "", 
        "properties": [
        ], 
        "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.phpjk.gif", 
        "fb_object_type": "album", 
        "fb_object_id": "4391044992857139135"
      },
      { 
        ... //Photo 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ty very much , i'll check tommorow :)

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible now that FQL has been deprecated?

Comment: @berserkia I think you can use graph api like this: `POSTID?fields=attachments`, this will return the same structure as you can see above.

Comment: @iamkhush I have checked it out right now and it seems to work for me. If you try it in the Graph API Explorer, there is in the connections options.

Comment: @Gaucho_9: I have a post with object_id 719638738118985 in the stream. I can get the details using Get call to /v2.2/719638738118985. When I try /v2.2/719638738118985?fields=attachments, the error says its a nonexistent field. How do i get the connections?

Comment: @iamkhush I inspect your post and I have seen that this post have an image. You can access the image object with `v2.2/719638738118985?fields=images`. There aren't attachments in this post.

Comment: @Gaucho_9: This returns different sizes of the same image. We want all images in same post.

Comment: @iamkhush: Yes it's true. But when I go to post link: `https://www.facebook.com/nh7weekender/photos/a.719638488119010.1073741880.110400542376144/719638738118985/?type=1` there is only one photo, so no attachments there. I think the attachments connections is only visible when there are more than one image. Can you try it on a post with two images?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Stéphane Bruckerts answer; you're after `attachments`. So I'd recommend simply requesting the `attachments` field in your graph request.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is a few years old, it still comes up when searching for this topic.

Facebook (Meta) Graph API has changed. Current Facebook (Meta) Graph API is version 13.0.

The best endpoint I found was to use the "/feed" URI slug, with "fields=attachments". Simply cURL / GET:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/$PAGEID/feed?access_token=$AUTHTOKEN&fields=attachments,full_picture,id,message,story
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v13.0/page/feed