# Retrieve all photos in facebook post with graph api

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

Hey all I am trying to use Rest FB to retrieve all photos from a post on facebook. However I am only ever able to pull back the first image of the post.

I have tried various JSON fields to pull this data but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Post posts = facebookClient.fetchObject(post.getId(), Post.class, Parameter.with("fields", "object_id"));
```

Comment: You need to use FQL api. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371424/how-can-i-get-all-photos-in-one-post-using-graph-api